# UML Event Tables: Differences between Event & Trigger, Intermidiate Responses

Tags: uml

Suppose the event/use-case "Buy Online", in the event table, the entry may look like

- Event: Customer buys products online
- Trigger: *Same as Event?*
- Source: Customer
- Use Case: Buy Online
- Response: Confirmation Code, Validate Credit Card
- Destination: Customer, Payment Verification System

If a Payment Verification System is called in the process to Validate Credit Card, do I include it? It isit the final response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not the final response, but only a part of this use case.
The `Validate Credit Card` is an **extension** (not an include) of the main use case, as it is optional (there are other way to pay online).